Unable to show duplicate file's size on PowerShell
I am currently working on a script that needs to do the following :

Find all duplicate files on a specific folder based on their hash
Display their path and size

Right now, finding the duplicate files and showing their paths work but I'm unable to display their size
Here's what the script looks like right now :
$srcDir = "C:\Users\test\Documents\folder"
Get-ChildItem -Path $srcDir -File -Recurse | Group -Property Length `
    | where { $_.Count -gt 1 } | select -ExpandProperty Group | Get-FileHash `
    | Group -Property Hash | where { $_.count -gt 1 }| foreach { $_.Group | select Path}

And here's the output :
Path                                                                           
----                                                                           
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file.pdf                   
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file_copy.pdf                           
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file.docx              
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file_copy.docx
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file_copy_2.docx                
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file.rdp                           
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file_copy.rdp                                   
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file.xlsx                            
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file_copy.xlsx      

I thought the "length" property was what I've been looking for so I edited the last line of the script  :
| Group -Property Hash | where { $_.count -gt 1 }| foreach { $_.Group | select Path, Length}

However, the output just shows an empty row
Path                                                                            Length
----                                                                            ------
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file.pdf                   
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file_copy.pdf                           
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file.docx              
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file_copy.docx
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file_copy_2.docx                
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file.rdp                           
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file_copy.rdp                                   
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file.xlsx                            
C:\Users\test\Documents\folder\Test_file_copy.xlsx      

Despite doing some research online, I couldn't find any answer about what I'm doing wrong
Thank you in advance for your help.

If you run just the first line of the above pipeline you will see that the results of the Group clause, is to list the files in the following colums: "Count" :  the number of files in thsi group, "Name" : the filelength value, "Group" : the file name. So you need to parse that data into the format that you want.

You better first match the size (as none of the other files might have the same size) before you do the expensive Get-FileHash, see: How to speed up ForEach-Object MD5/hash check.

Basically the issue with your code is in the last foreach { $_.Group | select Path, Length }, these objects no longer have a Length property as they're the output from Get-FileHash. The easiest way to do it would be to query the file's .Length once again however there is a bit of an overhead involved in doing this.
$srcDir = "C:\Users\test\Documents\folder"

Get-ChildItem -Path $srcDir -File -Recurse |
    Group-Object -Property Length |
    Where-Object Count -GT 1 |
    ForEach-Object Group |
    Get-FileHash |
    Group-Object Hash |
    Where-Object Count -GT 1 |
    ForEach-Object Group |
    Select-Object Path, Hash, @{ N = 'Length'; E = { [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($_.Path).Length }}

If you want to make your code more efficient but also more complicated you can use a hashtable ($map in the example) to hold the .Length of each path:
$srcDir = "C:\Users\test\Documents\folder"
$map = @{}

Get-ChildItem -Path $srcDir -File -Recurse |
    Group-Object -Property Length |
    Where-Object Count -GT 1 |
    ForEach-Object {
        foreach ($item in $_.Group) {
            $map[$item.FullName] = $item.Length
            $item
        }
    } |
    Get-FileHash |
    Group-Object Hash |
    Where-Object Count -GT 1 |
    ForEach-Object Group |
    Select-Object Path, Hash, @{ N = 'Length'; E = { $map[$_.Path] }}

